# What could make celery worker becoming unresponsive after a few tasks?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

My workers are stopping after a few (<50) tasks.

I have a very simple client/worker setup. The client post the task via `func.delay(...)` then enter a while loop to wait for the completion of all the tasks (i.e checking the `ready()` method of the `AsyncResult`). I use `rabbitmq` for the broker and the result backend.

The setup works...for a while. After a few tasks, the client doesn't receive anything and the worker seems to be idle (there is not output in the console anymore).

(The machine I work on is a bit old so a resource problem is not impossible. Still, at 50 tasks that runs for 2secs, I cannot say the system is under heavy load).

Comment: I'm currently fixing a deadlock in celery, the fixes are in the master branches if you want to try it out, see this bug: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1352

Comment: I had a similar problem and instead of `if foo.ready()` I went to `if foo.status == 'SUCCESS'` and my problems seem to have vanished.